# Has the Orange Revolution improved the fairness of Ukrainian elections according to independent observers?

Tags: election, democracy, ukraine, protests, grassroots

In late 2004, the [Orange Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Revolution) took place in Ukraine after elections that were accompanied by widescale corruption and fraud. Initially, Yanukovych was declared the winner. The protests resulted in new elections, closely monitored by international observers. These elections were won by Yushchenko. However, in 2010, Yanukovych returned to power in [apparently fair elections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_presidential_election,_2010).

Many participants in the Orange revolution may have been disappointed in the return to power of Yanukovych. But if this was in free and fair elections, and if elections since then have been free and fair, maybe the actual achievement was not to drive Yanukovych out, but to improve Ukrainian democracy. Has the Orange revolution had a lasting positive influence on the fairness of elections in Ukraine? By positive influence, I mean that the elections are considered fair according to independent observers. So the question consists of two parts:

- Have elections since 2004 been fairer than the 2004 one, according to independent observers?
- If yes, can this be attributed to the Orange Revolution?

Comment: Also, you may wish to define a bit more formally what you mean by "fairness of elections".

Comment: What do you mean under "independent observers"?

Comment: @Anixx I acknowledge that this is hard to define objectively...

Comment: @gerrit I suggest a term "external observers".

Comment: Sure, since "independent observers" are defined as exactly those who support it!

Comment: interesting thing was implemented in last russian presidential election. all polling stations across whole country were equipped with webcameras: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-16706779. it was known instances when cheaters got caught with stuffing ballots into polling boxes etc. i guess some district results were challenged in the courts with little luck by opposition groups. that's however was where democracy ended.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer up front: Yes, election conditions in Ukraine improved after the Orange Revolution, according to independent observers.

The [OSCE](http://www.osce.org/) is one of the gold standards for independent observers of elections, and has been invited to observe all elections in Ukraine since the 1990s. Their reports are all available [on the web-page dedicated to Ukrainian elections](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine?page=1). Those web pages also contain significant additional information.

### Elections Prior to 2004

Elections prior to 2004 were problematic at best, with major shortfalls. In 1999, for example [enter link description here](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/15000?download=true), the observers noted:

> The Law on Elections of the President of Ukraine was adopted on 25 March 1999.... [But] selective interpretation and enforcement of legal provisions at various levels of the State structure prevented the uniform application of the law. *As a result candidates were not competing on a level-playing field in the pre-election period, and the election disputes and appeal procedures generally did not provide the complainants with effective means to seek redress prior to the election.*
>
> Emphasis added

In 2002 [the observers wrote](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/14947?download=true):

> While Ukraine met in full or in part a number of commitments such as universality, transparency, freedom and accountability, it failed to guarantee a level playing field, an indispensable condition to ensure the fairness of the process.

### 2004 Election

The 2004 election was a pivot point for Ukrainian democracy. The first vote, and the second vote were not truly fair, but the vote called after the "Orange Revolution" showed a shift in attitude by the Ukrainian government towards democratic reform. At the time [observers wrote](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/14674?download=true):

> The 2004 presidential election in Ukraine was a highly competitive contest, which offered voters a genuine  choice  between  a  plurality  of  candidates.  While  the  31  October  (first  round)  and  21  November  (second  round)  votes  failed  to  meet  a  considerable  number  of  OSCE  Commitments,  Council  of  Europe  and  other  international  standards  for  democratic  elections,  the  26  December  repeat  second  round  vote  brought  Ukraine  substantially  closer  to  meeting  them.  The  improvement  was most clearly demonstrated in the media coverage, the overall conduct of the campaign and the transparency  in  the  CEC  performance,  including  the  immediate  publication  of  polling  station  results.  These  measures  stand  in  stark  contrast  to  the  previous  votes,  and  demonstrate  that  when  a  clear  political  will  is  evident  to  conduct  an  election  in  line  with  OSCE  commitments,  much  can  ultimately be achieved in a short time period.

In essence, immediately after the Orange Revolution, conditions improved.

### Post-2004 Elections

From 2004 to 2012, Ukrainian elections have received mostly positive reports from the OSCE. In [2006](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/19595?download=true), [2007](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/29970?download=true) and [2010](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/67844?download=true) the OSCE observers reported that the elections were mostly in line with standards for free elections. In each case, however, the observers did report that problems continued to exist, and recommend improvements. The most severe rebuke came in the 2007 report which warned:

> However,  the  IEOM  also  noted  some  areas  of concern,  including  some  recent  amendments  to  the  election  law,  the  inadequate  quality  of voter lists (VLs), and possible disenfranchisement of voters who crossed the state border after 1 August 2007.

In 2012, the quality of Ukrainian elections declined dramatically. The [OSCE observers reported](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/98578?download=true):

> ...certain aspects of the pre-election period constituted a step backwards compared with recent national elections. In particular, these elections were characterized by the lack of a level playing field, caused primarily by the abuse of administrative resources, lack of transparency of campaign and party financing, and the lack of balanced  media  coverage.  While  the  voting  and  counting  processes  on  election  day  were  assessed
>   positively  overall,  the  tabulation  of  results  was  negatively  assessed  in  nearly  half  of  the  electoral  districts  observed.  Post  election  day,  the  integrity  of  the  results  in  some  districts  appeared  to  be  compromised  by  instances  of  manipulation  of  the  results  and  other  irregularities,  which  were  not  remedied by the Central Election Commission (CEC) or the courts. "

This is the election which sparked the [Euro-Maidan movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euromaidan). Tensions which led to violence in the Eastern Provinces continued during the 2013 elections, but [those elections were reported as free and fair](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/110818?download=true) for the provinces which participated. The ongoing conflict has continued to mar national elections, but [in both](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/120549?download=true)[2014 elections](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/132556?download=true) and [in 2015](http://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/ukraine/223641?download=true), reports by the OSCE were positive.

Answer (score 0):

There are no independent observers in reality. The most external observer organizations are directly or indirectly sponsored by the USA or their allied countries as part of various pro-democracy programs. Arguably, these organizations play role of political instruments which provide "alternative" election results for each country, obtained by their own methods and serve as basis of whether the US accepts the official results or commands a revolution.

Recently the [Commonwealth of Independent States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_of_Independent_States) (CIS) countries also instituted certain international "observer" organizations that watch the elections in CIS, and their conclusions usually radically oppose what the Western observers say.

As to the elections in Ukraine, according the western observers, all instances where a pro-Western (pro-NATO) candidate wins are declared fair while when a pro-Russian(not necessary pro-Putin) candidate wins, declared less fair.

After Yanukovich was re-elected, the western organizations started to drop Ukraine's ratings of freedom of press and other indicators. For example, [Reporters Without Borders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporters_Without_Borders) radically dropped their "freedom of press" index of Ukraine after Yanukovich's elections, [according to them](http://en.rsf.org/press-freedom-index-2010,1034.html) this was the result of "the slow and steady deterioration in press freedom since Viktor Yanukovych’s election as president in February"

In reality though there is no change in the actual situation. The press enjoys just the same mode of operation as it did for more than a decade. So these ratings mostly published to exercise pressure on Ukraine.

Regarding elections, arguably the first and the second elections of Yanukovich were at about the same level of fairness. Yanukovich is arguably one of the most popular politician in Ukraine. His opponent in the second elections Yulia Tymoshenko was also quite popular, but Yuschenko was never much popular, and now widely hated.

That said, the elections where Yushenko was declared the winner were the only grossly unfair elections in recent Ukrainian history. They were impacted by the "revolutionary" riots, the Supreme Court nullification of the election (under international pressure from the West) and were accompanied by a prominent propaganda campaign in western media.

Comment: *«The most external observer organizations are directly or indirectly sponsored by the USA»* — and we must believe that none are sponsored by the Russia. Nice try, Vladimir, nice try.

Comment: @bytebuster there are some, recently. You can see it from my answer

Comment: Thing is that it's pointless to discuss the independence of the referees to uphold the rules of the game if the players are not willing to stick to playing the game in the first place.

Comment: This answer is like if someone said "What did referees call that last play?" and your response is "I reject the premise of referees, as there can be no truly adjudicated response without social oppression which is unjust." That kind of BS may fly in competitive debate, but here we are looking for answers, not deconstruction of social constructs.

Comment: You paint Reporters Without Borders "freedom of press" index as a political tool without fundation. Your paragraph starting from "In reality though there is no change in the actual situation." is not documented at all. But actually RWB's reports are very detailled: https://rsf.org/en/reports/temptation-control-report-fact-finding-visit-ukraine .

Comment: A more recent report: https://Frsf.org/sites/default/files/journalists_and_media_in_ukraine_-_rsf_2016.pdf/en/reports/temptation-control-report-fact-finding-visit-ukraine . The reasons their rating of freedom of press in Ukrain dropped is due, i.e. to desappearance of journalists or limitations of media broadcasts.